# How to anchor the first HTML child to the left and the last one - to the right

Tags: html, css

Please, consider the following trivial example: http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/vtLrt/

As you can see, it prints:

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3
```

What I would like to see is:

```
A1                B1
A2                B2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3
```

I.e. the first element is anchored to the left (A1, A2, A3) and the last one - to the right (B1, B2, G3).

Can I do it without JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: you said you want `B1, B2, B3` to the extreme right, but your example shows something different

Just give `float: right;` to `.anchorToRight`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vtLrt/6/)

CSS

```
.anchorToRight {
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: Stupid me, so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen you have added class `anchorToRight`. Float this class to right.

```
.anchorToRight{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now Define your Class `.char.anchortoRight` in your css   `float : right`

**As like this**

```
.char.anchorToRight{
float:right;
}
```

**[*Live demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/vtLrt/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this css into your css file.

`.anchorToRight{

   float:right;

}`